# Application showing login page even after user is logged in Django

Tags: django, authentication, redirect

When I log in to the Django project and then press the back button or enter the login page url, I am getting the Login page again even when the user is authenticated. I have tried adding the `redirect_authenticated_user` as in the code below:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.conf.urls import url

admin.autodiscover()
admin.site.login = login_required(admin.site.login)

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('accounts/login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(redirect_authenticated_user=True), name='login'),
]
```

Not sure if I have implemented something incorrectly.

Comment: can you upload your `sign in` view ?

Comment: swap `path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),` with `path('accounts/login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(redirect_authenticated_user=True), name='login'),`, I think this should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to swap the order of your url patterns like this:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(redirect_authenticated_user=True), name='login'),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

When you try to access an endpoint, Django matches it with the first suitable url in your urlpatterns (In your case it was default django login with no parameters passed)